# How to open SQL Server 2008 R2 Configuration manager in Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-8

In Windows 8.1, i can't find Configuration manager of SQL Server 2008R2. I have already followed the steps as specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683100/sql-server-configuration-manager-express-2012) question. But Configuration manager is not showing up even after entering 'SQLServerManager10.msc' in Search. Please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: I always use this press win+F and type configuration manager ,it will be listed in any of the sub lists ,i can't test it since i just uninstalled it due to the lack of the old start button!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and install something like ClassicShell (alternatives are available) which will give you back proper Win7 type start button functionality. It's gratis and stupid button aside (it can be changed but I think all of them look silly) it does exactly what it says on the tin. Windows 8 is  a dogs dinner and totally unsuited to anything but the most casual of users on a desktop.

Answer (score 13):

Open run command window using "Windows+R" type mmc.exe after console opened from file menu choose SQLSERVERMANAGER10.

Or you can type "SQLSERVERMANAGER10.msc" in run command window.

Comment: couldn't find this :/

Answer (score 4):

Here's where I found it:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212(v=sql.130).aspx

NOT pleased with this note:
"Because SQL Server Configuration Manager is a snap-in for the Microsoft Management Console program and not a stand-alone program, SQL Server Configuration Manager does not appear as an application in newer versions of Windows." Meaning it's basically undiscoverable by new DBA's. Glad I got in before Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8, SQL Server Configuration Manager shortcut is located in:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2008\Configuration Tools
```

Please note that ProgramData is a hidden folder. I suggest you create a shortcut on your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to open SSCM in Windows 8.1, I actually only have 2012 installed currently after refreshing my laptop but previously had 2008 R2 installed and it worked the same way for me.

Bring up the start menu:

[image]

You can also access this by using the search function of the start menu, by just typing `Configuration` you should get similar results:

[image]